# Postman and setting up a variable in the body of x-www-form-urlencoded request

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

So I'm trying to use chained request with Postman, where the first request will pass the data to the next request and I would use that data as a body. I was able to that, however there is an issue if there is `x-www-form-urlencoded` type of request involved because Postman will convert this:

Request body:

```
{{data}}
```

Into this:

```
{{data}: ""
```

Is there maybe a way to tell Postman not to add a colon in case variable is set as a body ?

Comment: What does your Postman request body look like? Is the value of `{{data}}` just a single piece of data? It's difficult to know what you're doing without an image etc.

Comment: well the data variable is in a format like this: property1: value1\r\n property1:value2\r\n and so on, that is the format the server expects and I can't change it.

Comment: @Zed I am trying out similar activity , have you found any solution

Comment: @prateeksarda Thank you for reminding me, I have answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no direct solution for this issue, so I had to find a way around. What I did was, create environment variables and then hard code key names and values that are expected in the request body:

Step1: Request1 - (Tests tab)

```
function setEnvironmentVars(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        postman.setEnvironmentVariable(prop, obj[prop]);
    }
}

setEnvironmentVars(data);
postman.setNextRequest("Request2");
```

So instead of passing the `data` object to `Request2`, I am creating env variable for each property in the data object, which will be accessible directly. This is executed automatically after the `Request 1` completes.

Step2: Request2 (Body tab)

In the `Request 2`, I set the request type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and then bulk edited the body with keys and env vars as values:

```
VAR1:{{VAR1}}
VAR2:{{VAR2}}
```

This solution for works very well, as the key names are always the same.

Comment: I had an issue created for Postman Labs team on Github who have responded with a solution
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5553